# how to hide and show the uiview when same bar button item oress

Tags: jquery, ios, objective-c, uiview

i create a right bar buttton item programatically. Andi place one UIVIEW in my view controller. And i have adde the action for my `bar button item`. But now what i have did is, first time my UIVIEW will be hidden. And when my bar button item press my UIVIEW should be show.

What i need is , when same button click my same UIVIEW should hide and show.Here is my code;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _barButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    UIBarButtonItem *chkmanuaaly = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Demo "style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(nextview)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=chkmanuaaly;

    RightMenu.hidden = YES;




}
-(void)nextview{
    NSLog(@"Right button pressed");

    RightMenu.hidden = NO;



}
```

How can i hide again i press my same `right bar button item`.

Please help me out.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked this code.This will work:

```
@implementation viewcontroller
    bool isShown = false;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        _barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
        _barButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

        UIBarButtonItem *chkmanuaaly = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Demo "style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(nextview)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=chkmanuaaly;

        RightMenu.hidden = YES;




    }
    -(void)nextview{
        NSLog(@"Right button pressed");

        if (!isShown) {
            RightMenu.hidden = NO;

            isShown = true;
        } else {
             RightMenu.hidden = YES;
            isShown = false;
        }



    }
```

Let me know, if it's work.

Comment: Yes, perfect and simple.Tq dude